# Per-application volume control

Tags: 12.10, windows-7, kubuntu, lubuntu, volume-control

Is there a way to get per-application volume control similar to Windows 7? I am looking for a way to do this in both Lubuntu and Kubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using gnome desktop environment then install [this](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/212/advanced-volume-mixer/) extension.

Comment: I am looking for a solution for Lubuntu and/or Kubuntu.

Comment: you can install gnome on Lubuntu/Kubuntu as well :)

Comment: But then why would I use them? :) I use them for the environment.

Answer (score 1):

**KDE/KMIX/MPRIS2**

The Kubuntu/KDE (KDE 4.8 or later) default mixer is supporting per-application volume control with the applications that support the MPRIS2.

More: http://kmix5.wordpress.com/ --> http://kmix5.wordpress.com/2011/12/30/winter-of-69-welcome-kmix-v4/

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that. Do you know of anything for LXDE?